# Dispatching from a runtime parameter to different overloads

Tags: c++, pattern-matching, c++17, template-meta-programming

Suppose I have a set of types :

```
constexpr std::tuple<int,double,string> my_types;
```

a set of values to identify them:

```
constexpr std::array<const char*,3> my_ids = {"int","double","string"}; // const char* instead of string to be constexpr-compatible
```

and an overload set

```
template<class T> bool my_fun(my_type complex_object) { /* some treatment depending on type T */ }
```

I have a manually dispatching function like that:

```
string my_disp_fun(my_type complex_object) {
  const char* id = get_info(complex_object);
  using namespace std::string_literals;
  if (id == "int"s) {
    return my_fun<int>(complex_object);
  } else if (id == "double"s) {
    return my_fun<double>(complex_object);
  } else if (id == "string"s) {
    return my_fun<string>(complex_object);
  } else {
    throw;
  }
}
```

Because I see this pattern coming again and again with a different `my_fun` every time, I would like to replace it by something like that:

```
struct my_mapping {
  static constexpr std::tuple<int,double,string> my_types;
  static constexpr std::array<const char*,3> my_ids = {"int","double","string"}; // const char* instead of string to be constexpr-compatible
}

string my_disp_fun(my_type complex_object) {
  const char* id = get_info(complex_object);
  return
    dispatch<my_mapping>(
      id, 
      my_fun // pseudo-code since my_fun is a template
    );
}
```

How to implement the dispatch function? I am pretty confident it can be done but so far, I can't think of a reasonably nice API that would still be implementable with template metaprograming tricks.

I am sure people already had the need for this kind of problem. Is there a name for this pattern? I don't really know how to even qualify it in succinct technical terms...

Side question: is it related to the pattern matching proposal? I'm not sure because the paper seems more interested in the matching part, not generating branchs from that, right ?

Comment: Are you sure that the `(id == "int")` works for you?

Comment: @AmirKirsh Fixed, thanks

Comment: Why are you using tuple?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Here I am just using the type of the tuple as a type container. But any type container would do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leverage variant.

```
template<class T>struct tag_t{using type=T};
template<class T>constexpr tag_t<T> tag={};
template<class...Ts>
using tag_enum = std::variant<tag_t<Ts>...>;
```

now `tag_enum` is a type stores a type at runtime as a value.  Its runtime representation is an integer (!), but C++ knows that integer represents a specific type.

We now just have to map your strings to integers

```
using supported_types=tag_enum<int, double, std::string>;

std::unordered_map<std::string, supported_types> name_type_map={
  {"int", tag<int>},
  {"double", tag<double>},
  {"string", tag<std::string>},
};
```

this map can be built from an array and a tuple if you want, or made global somewhere, or made into a function.

The point is, a mapping of any kind to a tag_enum can be used to auto dispatch a function.

To see how:

```
string my_disp_fun(my_type complex_object) {
  const char* id = get_info(complex_object);
  return std::visit( [&](auto tag){
    return my_fun<typename decltype(tag)::type>( complex_object );
  }, name_type_map[id] };
}
```

refactoring this to handle whatever level of automation you want should be easy.

If you adopt the convention that you pass `T` as a `tag_t` as the first argument it gets even easier to refactor.

```
#define RETURNS(...)\
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }

#define MAKE_CALLER_OF(...) \
  [](auto&&...args) \
  RETURNS( (__VA_ARGS__)(decltype(args)(args)...) )
```

now you can easily wrap a template function into an object

```
template<class F>
auto my_disp_fun(my_type complex_object F f) {
  const char* id = get_info(complex_object);
  return std::visit( [&](auto tag){
    return f( tag, complex_object );
  }, name_type_map[id] }; // todo: handle failure to find it
}
```

then

```
std::string s = my_disp_fun(obj, MAKE_CALLER_OF(my_fun));
```

does the dispatch for you.

(In theory we could pass the template parameter in the macro, but the above macros are generically useful, while one that did wierd tag unpacking are not).

Also we can make a global type map.

```
template<class T>
using type_entry = std::pair<std::string, tag_t<T>>;
#define TYPE_ENTRY_EX(NAME, X) type_entry<X>{ NAME, tag<X> }
#define TYPE_ENTRY(X) TYPE_ENTRY_EX(#X, X)

auto TypeTable = std::make_tuple(
  TYPE_ENTRY(int),
  TYPE_ENTRY(double),
  TYPE_ENTRY_EX("string", std::string)
);

template<class Table>
struct get_supported_types_helper;
template<class...Ts>
struct get_supported_types_helper<std::tuple<type_entry<Ts>...>> {
  using type = tag_enum<Ts...>;
};
template<class Table>
using get_supported_types = typename get_supported_types_helper<Table>::type;
```

From that you can do things like make the unordered map from the `TypeTable` tuple automatically.

All of this is just to avoid having to mention the supported types twice.

Comment: Thanks, it is almost perfect. What I don't like is the fact that `tag`, which is an implementation detail, must be specified by the user: once in the body of `my_disp_fun`, and one in the signature of `my_fun`. But I don't think there is a way to hide it. In fact, I guess I am forced to declare `my_fun(Tag, ...)` instead of `my_fun(...)` so that the "lambda-isation" made by MAKE_CALLER_OF works right?

Comment: You can do some glue for that, but I wouldn't.  Explicit template parameters on functions are meh; tag based dispatching is a better plan, as it allows overload resolution to be used, which us much better.

Answer (score 2):

Since your functions have the same signature, you can use a `std::map` to map the ids to function pointers, eg:

```cpp
template<class T>
std::string my_fun(my_type complex_object)
{
    /* some treatment depending on type T */ 
    return ...;
}

using my_func_type = std::string(*)(my_type);

const std::map<std::string, my_func_type> my_funcs = {
    {"int", &my_fun<int>},
    {"double", &my_fun<double>},
    {"string", &my_fun<std::string>}
};

std::string my_disp_fun(my_type complex_object)
{
    const char *id = get_info(complex_object);
    auto iter = my_funcs.find(id);
    if (iter == my_funcs.end())
        throw ...;
    return iter->second(complex_object);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/w7GQgh)

Comment: I am sorry but this is not what I am looking for. I edited the post to give precisions. The problem with your solution is that I would like to do it automatically for many "my_fun". Here it would mean defining as many std::map, which would be as repetitive as corresponding if statements

Comment: "*this is not what I am looking for*" - then you did not present your issue correctly, because this does solve what you actually asked for. Did you look at the demo I created for you? "*I would like to do it automatically for many "my_fun". Here it would mean defining as many std::map*" -  there is only 1 `map` needed, holding as many entries as you have types defined for `my_fun`, same as with your `my_ids` array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is what you are looking for. But you can do it without the need to hold an additional array with the types:

```
// overload visitor trick
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
// deduction guide
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

int main() {
    std::tuple<int, double, const char*> tup = {10, 2.5, "hello"};
    auto f = overloaded {
        [](int arg){std::cout << arg << " + 3 = " << arg + 3 << std::endl;},
        [](double arg){std::cout << arg << " * 2 = " << arg * 2 << std::endl;},
        [](const std::string& arg){std::cout << "string: " << arg << std::endl;}
    };
    std::apply([&](const auto&... e){ (f(e), ...);}, tup);
}
```

Code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3bfdd35f89ceeff9

Comment: I am sorry but this is not what I want to do. Based on some information on an object, I want to call a different function on that object. If the object contains "int" I want to call my_fun<int> on it, if "double", then call my_fun<double>... etc

Comment: "*Based on some information on an object, I want to call a different function on that object*" - That is *exactly* what the example I gave you does. So why do you say it does not solve your issue?